# How to Design a Multi-Modules Play Application

Tags: playframework-2.0

Given a Play application consisting of several modules and assuming they don't known anything about each other, I'm wondering what's the correct way to correlate their output.

Suppose an application consists of a main module, an authentication module, and a payment module. The authentication module provides functionality for signing up and signing, the payment module provides functionality for paying via credit card, and the main module runs the business.

When a user signs up, the registration form - which is part of the authentication module - asks for username, password, address, etc... and hopefully also for credit card details. Credit card details should be managed by the payment module, but it would be nice if the user could provide them while signing up. This means the authentication module needs the functionality provided by the payment module for registering a new credit card... and the main module should somehow enable this.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Given a Play application consisting of several modules and assuming
>   they don't known anything about each other

Why do you assume that? Modules can depend on each other. One of the main reasons of modularisation is that the dependencies are well separated from each other to make it clear which part of the software depends on other parts. 
The other main reason is reusability.

For example: Usually I use the same authentication module in my every play projects. In addition, I usually create a module for my data layer, I mean I separate all of my entities to another module and other modules that use this model entities can depend on it.

Another suggestion: put your components that you want to make replaceable in a separated module. For an instance, I have different implementation for an sms sending service (with a common interface), implemented in their own modules. So if I wan't to replace the sms implementation, all I need to do is replace the dependency in the core project's Build.scala.

I hope these ideas have helped you to move forward...

Comment: I do agree ;-) but what's about common HTML templates? It would make sense to have a single main.scala.html used by all the sub-modules so that they have the same appearance... Thanks.